# How can i remove empty spaces from lines in a string on each line begining and end?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a string variable called combindedString;
It's content format looks like that:

```
שרת המשפטים לבני: ''לא חשוב אם החטופים מתל אביב או מטלמון''
דווח במקור בתאריך: 16.06.14  שעה : 11:04

מורעלים לשנאה: ילדות פלסטיניות חוגגות ''שלוש גלעד שליט''
דווח במקור בתאריך: 16.06.14  שעה : 11:36

לידיעתכם: בדקות האחרונות מסתובבות שמועות וואטסאפ שקריות נוספות
דווח במקור בתאריך: 16.06.14  שעה : 11:36

ח''כ רגב: אם אסירים ביטחוניים מבקשים למות - יש לאפשר להם
דווח במקור בתאריך: 16.06.14  שעה : 11:32


      3 נערים נחטפו ע״י חמאס - אשכול מרוכז ומתעדכן (#12)
דווח במקור בתאריך: 16.06.14  שעה : 00:37

כל עובד בטאבו יקבל&#8232; 30 אלף שקל בגלל הכנסת מערכת מחשוב חדשה
דווח במקור בתאריך: 16.06.14  שעה : 07:46

סרילנקה: אספסוף בודהיסטי תקף מוסלמים, 3 הרוגים, 80 פצועים, עוצר
דווח במקור בתאריך: 16.06.14  שעה : 10:42
```

There are places in the string like this part:

```
ח''כ רגב: אם אסירים ביטחוניים מבקשים למות - יש לאפשר להם
    דווח במקור בתאריך: 16.06.14  שעה : 11:32


          3 נערים נחטפו ע״י חמאס - אשכול מרוכז ומתעדכן (#12)
    דווח במקור בתאריך: 16.06.14  שעה : 00:37
```

That between the date&time and the next text line there are more then one spaces and also the next text line is look like there are spaces in it's begining:

```
      3 נערים נחטפו ע״י חמאס - אשכול מרוכז ומתעדכן (#12)
```

I tried to use trim on the combindedString but it didn't help or changed anything.

The combindedString should be like this:

```
שרת המשפטים לבני: ''לא חשוב אם החטופים מתל אביב או מטלמון''
דווח במקור בתאריך: 16.06.14  שעה : 11:04

מורעלים לשנאה: ילדות פלסטיניות חוגגות ''שלוש גלעד שליט''
דווח במקור בתאריך: 16.06.14  שעה : 11:36

לידיעתכם: בדקות האחרונות מסתובבות שמועות וואטסאפ שקריות נוספות
דווח במקור בתאריך: 16.06.14  שעה : 11:36
```

In between each two lines ( text and time&date ) one empty/space line.

This is what i tried to do :

```
for (int i = 0; i < combindedString.Length; i++)
            {
                combindedString.Trim(combindedString[i]);
            }
            scroller1.TextToScroll = combindedString;
```

But it didn't fix it. How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable i.e. the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it appear as if you can do this.

So do

```
string[] ss = combindedString.Split(new string[] {"\n", "\r\n"}, 
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**Full Code**

```
for (int i = 0; i < ss.Length; i++)
    ss[i] = ss[i].Trim();

combindedString = String.Join("\n", ss);
scroller1.TextToScroll = combindedString;
```

Comment: Nikhil combindedString[i] = combindedString[i].Trim(); the problem is that combindedString[i] dose not contain Trim. Only combindedString contain Trim.

Comment: Nikhil your code seems to be ok just in the end i need to keep the combindedString format as it was before removing all spaces. I mean that each two lines to insert one empty line. I mean the first line is text then line of date&time then empty/space line. And so on. Just like i showed in my question at the beginning. The format of the string should be kept: text line date&time line space/empty line this is the format.

Comment: I just wanted to clean unneed spaces from each line or more then empty lines in between two lines. But in the end it should be: text line then date&time line then empty space line.

Answer (score 0):

Use Trim() method to remove leading and trailing spaces into a string

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx):

```
combindedString = Regex.Replace(combindedString, "\n( *)?", "\n").Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex` to replace any multiple spaces with one. It works between the words in any location:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", RegexOptions.None);
combindedString = regex.Replace(combindedString, @" ");
scroller1.TextToScroll = combindedString.Trim();
```